# Changing link text php from wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working with a client's wordpress affiliate site.

We are using two plugins in conjunction with each other.

- ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)
- EasyAzon (This inserts an affiliate link via shortcode into your post)

I have set up custom fields for this shortcode, and coded it into my them like this.

`<div class="top-link"> <?php the_field('link-button'); ?></div>`

This outputs:

"`<div class="top-link">
    <a href="http://www.theaffiliatelink.com/path/to/product">Buy Now</a>
 </div>`"

And now I want to use the same function "`<?php the_field('link-button'); ?>`" at the bottom of my page.

However I would like it to display text from yet another ACF field "`<?php the_field('bottom-link'); ?>`" within the anchor tag.

But if there is no text in that field, I want it to use the text "Click to buy on Amazon"

### So here is what I have:

```
<div class="top-link"><?php the_field('link-button'); ?></div>

<!-- The post content -->           

<div class="bottom-link"> <?php the_field('link-button'); ?></div>


<?php 
    $link = get_field('bottom-link');

    if (get_field('bottom-link') != '') {
        $link = get_field('bottom-link');
    }
    else {
        $link = "Click to Buy Amazon";
    }
?>


<script>
var link = '<?php echo $link; ?>';

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.bottom-link a').text(link);
});
</script>
```

I'm pretty new to both languages, and maybe complicating things a lot. Any thoughts would help!

Here is the dev site live if you're interested in looking at that.

http://tttrend.com/wtbag/gifts-for-men/general/test-post/

Comment: does the URL of the link stay the same in both cases? also do you have a way of getting the URL in a variable?

Comment: The URL is created by the shortcode along with several data attribute and the text. I've read something about DOMXPath for php to look for specific atts ,but my tests haven't worked using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do

```
<?php 
    $link = get_field('bottom-link');

    if (!isset($link) || empty($link) ) {
        $link = "Click to Buy Amazon";
    }
?>
```

Also if you are using the same field over and over, try getting the results in a variable and then using the variable instead. Using get_field, sends a request to the database and using it over and over again might slow your application down.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried this suggestion. It is returning "Click to buy on Amazon" wether I have   the field populated or not. Is it possible that get_field() is returning something invisible? I don't know how to check for that.

Comment: Try replacing empty($link) with $link != '', or just add another one besides the two